# What transaction isolation level prevents MariaDB from locking tables during a join?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb-10.5

I am using MariaDB 10.5.12. My query will join the `tbl_cus` table to a previous view, creating a new view. I am using MySQL Workbench with auto-commit enabled. During testing, the app connected to the `customers` table was not able to query data. My join simply reads from the `customers` table, joins it to the view, and `SELECT INSERT IGNORE`s into a separate table. How do I avoid locking the customer table on this join? Is there a proper transaction isolation level? This is my query structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ct_locations AS
    SELECT...
    FROM
        tbl_cus AS c_t
            LEFT JOIN
        tbl_loc AS c_l ON c_t.id = c_l.id;

INSERT IGNORE INTO c_a
SELECT
    id,...
    CASE
        WHEN
            datetime >= DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                    INTERVAL 8 HOUR),
                INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        THEN
            1
        ELSE 0
    END AS is_active
FROM
    ct_locations
ORDER BY datetime  DESC
;
```

In [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-transaction/#isolation-level), it does say that for `READ COMMITTED`,

> each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot.

I think `SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ-COMMITTED;` is not right. Using `tbl_cus AS c_t LEFT JOIN..` would cause `ct_locations` to join and read the entire `tbl_cus` table and thus lock it. If I use `READ-UNCOMMITTED` instead, will it solve the problem? MariaDB documentation says that `SELECT statements are performed in a non-locking fashion, but a possible earlier version of a row might be used.` I am willing to tolerate a dirty read since `tbl_cus` does not change often anyway.

I found some articles about query isolation levels but they focus on SQL servers.

- [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)

  This article does have a comment about a join that implies writers will not block readers if a CTE is used. I don't know if that applies to MariaDB or if it is possible with my query. My views join two different tables.
- [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation)

---

Rick James requested some details about the tables.

- This is the DDL create statement for `c_a`:

```
CREATE TABLE `c_a` (
  `customer_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime_logged` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `event_id_UNIQUE` (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

- These are the row counts for the tables involved.

1. Output table:
   `c_a`: 111,474
2. Tables for the `ct_locations` view:

- `c_t`: 252,115
- `tbl_loc`: 1,745

---

`EXPLAIN...` output for `INSERT IGNORE INTO c_a`:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1, PRIMARY, customer, ALL, , , , , 133, Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, <derived7>, ref, key0, key0, 147, customer.id, 2, 
1, PRIMARY, <derived4>, ALL, , , , , 4192, Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
7, LATERAL DERIVED, customer, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 146, customer.id, 1, Using where
7, LATERAL DERIVED, c, eq_ref, PRIMARY,FK_1e58a3b250f2d9170c04dbe7a87, PRIMARY, 1022, customer.city, 1,
4, DERIVED, c_t, ALL, , , , , 4192, Using temporary; Using filesort
```

`EXPLAIN...` results for the `SELECT` statement of `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ct_locations`:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,customer,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,133,
1,PRIMARY,<derived5>,ref,key0,key0,147,customer.id,2,
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4192,"Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)"
5,"LATERAL DERIVED",customer,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,146,customer.id,1,"Using where"
5,"LATERAL DERIVED",c,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,FK_1e58a3b250f2d9170c04dbe7a87",PRIMARY,1022,customer.city,1,
2,DERIVED,c_t,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4192,"Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

This is the query that I guess was blocked and prevented our web app from getting a list of users:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customer
ORDER BY email
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 20;
-- OFFSET will be set to 0 if querying the first "page" of customers.
```

This is the `EXPLAIN` result of that query:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,customer,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,133,"Using filesort"
```

Comment: "*each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads **its own fresh snapshot**.*" - This means each read will not get blocked because it'll be reading it's own version of the data. Also `JOIN`s don't inherently block queries, and reads don't block reads.

Comment: Is the "+ 8  HOUR" to compensate for mixing `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatypes?

Comment: Why have an `ORDER BY`?  I don't see that it impacts the results; it would impact the performance.

Comment: About now many rows in each table?  In the JOIN's output?  Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table?  Re cus and loc 1:1?  If so, why have them as separate tables?  (Another possible performance area.)  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?  (I may help to see datatypes, indexes, etc.)

Comment: @RickJames Yes, correct. I tried using CONVERT_TZ but it left out some results. It might be because `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(...)` does not return anything. The `ORDER BY` command is just to present the results in chronological order. You're right, it doesn't affect the results.

Comment: Let's see the `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for the two conflicting queries.

Comment: @RickJames I added the `EXPLAIN SELECT` results to the question. I can only guess at what query was blocked and caused users to get logged out, though.

Comment: "LIMIT will be set to 0..." -- perhaps you meant `OFFSET`?  The evils of OFFSET:  [_Pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)